# Foreach de un objeto c#

Tags: c#

Buenas tardes, lo que intento hacer es setear los atributos de una lista de objetos desde una tabla con dos for para la tabla y un foreach para los atributos del objeto. Estoy trabado en como asignarle el valor al atributo.

```
 /*recorre las filas*/
        for (var j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            var campo = new Campo();

            /*se para en cada fila y recorre las columnas*/
            for (var i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {

                var nombreCampo = dt.Columns[i].Caption;

                /*recorro las propiedades del objeto campo 
                 * y cuando nombreCampo==propertyInfo.Name 
                 * le asigno el valor de la celda segun cordenadas*/
                foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in campo.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    if (propertyInfo.Name == nombreCampo)
                    {
                        propertyInfo.SetValue( Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[j][i]));
                    }
                }


            }

        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que occurrio si te eliminar "Convert.ToString()"?

Comment: si, mismo error

Comment: Porque llamas Campo al objeto que en realidad deberia ser una Row ? los campos serian las propiedades. Creo que confuende un poco la linea  var campo = new Campo();  aconsejaria le definas otro nombre a esa clase

Comment: es que el objeto es un campo de la tabla. tengo toda la información del campo de la tabla que consulto en la Bd. Puede ser confuso, pero me entiendo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si analizamos la propiedad

[PropertyInfo.SetValue (Método)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh194291%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

veras que esta lleva dos parametros, por lo que deberi ser

```
propertyInfo.SetValue(campo, Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[j][i]));
```

Comment: Te juro que lo intente. pero hacia falta que lo dijeras vos y ahora anda

Comment: eso se llama, tener la bendición de un Microsoft MVP!

Answer (score 0):

Por cada fila es necesario crear una instancia de las clase Campo y la salves en una lista, de lo contrario vas a perder siempre el objeto en cada iteración.

Eso como primer punto. Ahora, para setear el valor de la propiedad es necesario que indiques a cuál objeto en el primer argumento mientras que el valor en el segundo.

```
propertyInfo.SetValue(campo, dt.Rows[j][i], null);
```

Si además, quisieras hacer una conversión al tipo de la propiedad podés hacer lo siguiente

```
propertyInfo.SetValue(campo, Convert.ChangeType(dt.Rows[j][i], propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
```